Unable to load connection: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017, connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
mongodb for vs code extension is not connecting to atlas mongodb and I am getting this error on
vs code
Unable to load connection: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017, connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
I try to connect mongodb by giving string
which is taken from atlas cloud mongodb

This question is similar to: Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

this is mongodb for vs code extension connection issue fixed

127.0.0.1:27017 and ::1:27017 connect to MongoDB running locally on your computer. Mongo Atlas is a cloud service and quite different to it.

I got fix.
1- mongodb must be installed local first
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass
2- give access
enter image description here

Compass is a client application to connect to a MongoDB. It has nothing to do with the problem in your question. In the second screenshot you white-list your IP but that has nothing to do with the error message your provided in the question. You are mixing several things.

Answer is incorrect. Question is not/mis - understood
